# Login to a webpage from my chrome extension

Tags: javascript, asp.net, web-services, asmx, google-chrome-extension

I 'd like to login to a webpage from my google chrome extension. and that webpage is not running in the background tab. so any ideas ?

My website uses regular login system. following is the code that calls the web service.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$('#submit').click(function() {

$.ajax(
{

type: "POST",
url: "http://localhost:1204/ChromeExtensionService.asmx/HelloWorld",
//data: '{"id":"' + currentObjId.toString() + '"}',
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
dataType: "json",
success: function (msg) {

alert('here');
alert(msg.d);
},

error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {

alert(xhr.responseText);
}
```

Comment: I guess that might be a security threat and browsers should keep you from trying it. Still I think it's possible.

Comment: I'm trying to call a web service from my website and whenever I try to call it right away , I get an authentication error, any ideas how solve this ?

Comment: Dude, don't post updates as answers. Edit your question instead. Stackoverflow isn't a forum!

Comment: okay , sorry about that. i'm kinda getting used to how things work around here :)

Answer (score 0):

If you ask how you can emulate login form submission see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5354029/login-to-website-with-chrome-extension-and-get-data-from-it/5354526#5354526).

Comment: thanks serg :) . actually, I'm trying to call a web service from my website and whenever I try to call it right away , I get an authentication error, any ideas how solve this ?

Comment: @ismail You need to provide some code and explain what sort of authentication is installed on your webservice.

Comment: sorry for the late reply. my website uses regular login system. following is the code that calls the web service.

$(document).ready(function () {

$('#submit').click(function() {

$.ajax(
{

type: "POST",
url: "http://localhost:1204/ChromeExtensionService.asmx/HelloWorld",
//data: '{"id":"' + currentObjId.toString() + '"}',
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
dataType: "json",
success: function (msg) {

alert('here');
alert(msg.d);
},

error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {

alert(xhr.responseText);
}