# Cannot login from Chrome extension to another site

Tags: cookies, google-chrome-extension, request, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to login into an online shopping site from Chrome extension, then scrape it.
There are three steps that happens when you do this from a browser.

1. Visit the site, the site gives you a cookie.
2. Go to the login page, send the aforementioned cookie, and username and password as params in POST.  The site gives you 5 more cookies.
3. call GET to a path within the site, along with five + one = total six cookies.

Now that works well in browser.  If I copy all the cookies from the browser into curl, the following call would work.

```
curl -X GET --header "Cookie: cookie1=value1; cookie2=value2; cookie3=value3; cookie4=value4; cookie5=value5; cookie6=value6" http://www.sitedomain.com/product_info.php?products_id=350799
```

However, how can I repeat this behavior in Google Chrome extension?  Nothing I do seems to be working, yes I added the domain to the manifest.json and I've tried request, requestify (both browserified) and XMLHttpRequest.  The requests seem fine (do include cookies) but the response I get seems to be the one I get when the site any receiving cookie.

manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Getting started example",
  "description": "This extension shows a Google Image search result for the current page",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },

  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "cookies",
    "https://sitedomain.com/*",
    "http://sitedomain.com/*",
    "https://www.sitedomain.com/*",
    "http://www.sitedomain.com/*"
  ]
}
```

The code I use (request version):

```
var request = require('request');
request = request.defaults({jar: true});

var jar = request.jar();
var cookie1 = request.cookie('cookie1=value1');
var cookie2 = request.cookie('cookie2=value2');
var cookie3 = request.cookie('cookie3=value3');
var cookie4 = request.cookie('cookie4=value4');
var cookie5 = request.cookie('cookie5=value5');
var cookie6 = request.cookie('cookie6=value6');

var url = "http://www.sitedomain.com";
jar.setCookie(cookie1, url);
jar.setCookie(cookie2, url);
jar.setCookie(cookie3, url);
jar.setCookie(cookie4, url);
jar.setCookie(cookie5, url);
jar.setCookie(cookie6, url);

request({uri: http://www.sitedomain.com/product_info.php?products_id=350799, jar: jar}, function (error, response, html) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        //breakpoint here and we did not receive the page after login
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5354029/login-to-website-with-chrome-extension-and-get-data-from-it